# Help connecting an Epson ET 2810 scanner

Tags: scanner

Ubuntu 20.04
Possibly need to install the following package but have no idea how to

epsonscan2-bundle-6.6.42.0.x86_64.deb.tar.gz

Scanner is detected bluetooth but shows as "Not set up"

Scanner is detected when I run scanimage -L

Attempts to scan with Document Scanner gets error message "Failed to scan" "Unable to start scan"

I am a beginner and i do not know how to install the above packages or know if that will help.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have the answer for you because I have wrestled with Epson's instructions while trying to install my V600 scanner. Epson's instructions are vague and mystical but after about a dozen attempts I have worked out a procedure. We are using the same Epson software so I will skip the download steps and tell you what I have done after that:

1. Move the downloaded file to `~` (home directory)
2. From the command line:

```
cd ~
tar xf [bundlename].deb.tar.gz
cd [bundlename].deb
./install.sh
sudo apt update
```

I, too, am a beginner.

Comment: I think I was able to install this but there has been no change. not sure if it was done correctly? Is there a way to check?

Comment: Upgraded to ubuntu 22.04 after above actions. Issues solved. Printer and Scanner working. Thanks @ QRP